# use all terminal space for printing in interactive R session

Tags: r, dataframe

when executing code in an interactive R session, I find that `data.frame`s as well as `tibble`s do not use all the available width of my terminal space, whereas simple print operations are indeed using all the space.

While not really a big deal necessarily, it is a nuisance and I'd like to understand if there's a way to make good use of the space when printing tabular data.

[image]

Comment: Set `op <- options(width=120)`, reset `options(op)`.

Comment: You might set `options(width = 200)` or anything you'd like. By default it's 80. In RStudio it's automatically adjusted to the available space but I'm not sure if this can be done in the command line

Comment: That works, thank you! Why don't you make this into a proper answer?

Comment: Since I see you use dplyr maybe you'll want to adjust the width for tibbles specifically, in that case you might use `options(pillar.width=)`

Comment: thanks, the pillar.width seems to automatically be adjusted when specificying ```options(width = 120)```